# How to include a function file in symfony2 in controller

Tags: php, symfony

Hi I have a file called payment.php it contains some functions related to payments and some multiple classess. So I want to include that file in my symfony2 Controller to access its all methods and classless. I am trying it as follows:

```
//File location is in src/AppBundle/Controller/payment.php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

require_once __DIR__.'/./payment.php';

//My controller
class ApiServicesController extends Controller
{
   $this->payment(array('txnId'=>1112548));
}
```

But I am not able to access the file and its methods.

I am using this approach because keeping it in /vendor directory it also not able to access because this file contains multiple classless in same files.

Please advice me how can I access this file in my controller.

thanks in advance

Comment: _But I am not able to access the file and its methods_  - Which methods?

Comment: $this->payment(array('txnId'=>1112548)); this mathod is defined in payment.php

payment() method.

Comment: ApiServicesController isn't a valid class

Comment: Why its a valid class I am already using this controller.what does it mean not valid class?

Comment: The class `ApiServicesController` should be in the file Controller/ApiServicesController.php

Comment: yes it is there already.

Comment: And `Payment` is a controller as well? Why do you even require it manually - it should be loaded via autoloading

Comment: Payment () is a method in payment.php , I require it manuly because this file contain multiple classess and methods, which is not able to import from vendor as well. It does not contain a single Class and its methods

Comment: Is this file created by you? Or do you have downloaded it from vendor?

Comment: I got this file from vendor payment gateway kit (payumoney). So need to integrate it in symfony2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If paymant.php have classes you need to make instance of that class to call method from it, that's like basic OOP stuff.

```
class ApiServicesController extends Controller
{
   $this->payment(array('txnId'=>1112548));
}
```

First of all, where is the method in this controller where you want to call your method? Then, why you are calling *payment* on *$this* if it comes from diffrent class. It should be something like this

```
class ApiServicesController extends Controller
{
   public function indexAction()
   {
       $somePaymentClass = new SomePaymantClass(); //whatever class you want from payment.php
       $somePaymentClass->payment(array('txnId'=>1112548));
   }
}
```

But iI strongly recommend to use it as a service and put it in some autoloader namespace.

Comment: Dear, I know that oops concept. The issue is payment.php has multiple classess, and different methods. its a single file I just inclide it in my controller, to access method payment():

Comment: $somePaymentClass = new SomePaymantClass(); //whatever class you want from payment.php : Note: The payment() method is not inside any class. it is as in that payment.php file

Comment: _>Dear, I know that oops concept_

By looking at your code, You do not ;)
If they are not in class just call them after include.
`payment(array('txnId'=>1112548))`
Don't call them on $this and dont call them outside method functions.

Do like this

`require_once("path/to/file.php");
class ApiServicesController extends Controller
{
   public function indexAction()
   {
         payment(array('txnId'=>1112548));
   }
}`

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a Payment class as a service and then you can use all functions of Payment class in controller. Please refer this document.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html

Comment: Yes , but that file payment.php already contain multiple classess in single file. How can I put them in a single class?

Comment: If this is your custom class I suggest you to create separate class files instead of keeping all in one. You can register all files as a service and use in any controller.

Comment: No that file (payment.php) I got from vendor payment gasteway kit (payumoney). That's why I am unable to do anything with in this. I need to integrate this payment gateway in symfony2 Application

Comment: Have you tried this bundle? https://packagist.org/packages/fsi/sylius-payu-bundle

Comment: Let me try this.